# SQL query to get colums from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, `Product` and `Prices`, and I want to get for each ID in `Product` table the `ID_Forn` and `min(Price)` from table `Prices`.

```
 Product                      Prices

| ID | Desc   |      | ID | ID_Forn | PRICE |
| -- | ------ |      | 1  | 101     | 10€   |
| 1  | Prod 1 |      | 1  | 102     | 11€   | 
| 2  | Prod 2 |      | 1  | 103     | 13€   |
| 3  | Prod 3 |      | 2  | 101     | 9€    |
| 4  | Prod 4 |      | 2  | 102     | 8€    |
```

With this query

```
SELECT 
    P.ID, 
    Price = (SELECT MIN(Price) 
             FROM Prices PP (NOLOCK) 
             WHERE P.ID = PP.ID)
FROM 
    Product P(NOLOCK)
```

I only get the `ID` and the `MIN(Price)`, and can't ever get `ID_Forn`.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to `join` to aggregated prices

Comment: Why are you spamming `nolock` everywhere? Do you specifically want unreliable results?

Comment: Provide a complete [mcve], i.e. also _specify_ the expected result. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: What version of SQL server, this looks to be a prime case to use a table value function cross/outer apply with sub query to get top price in ascending order.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the following will give you your desired results; here, for each correlated product row, the subquery is *applied* to return both columns, joining the tables using `Id`.

Depending on your data you might want to handle duplicates in a particular way, eg `with ties` or NULLs eg `isnull()`.

```
select p.Id, p.desc. pr.*
from Product p
outer apply (
  select top(1) Id_forn, Price
  from Prices pr
  where pr.Id = p.Id
  order by PRICE 
)pr;
```